# Mass human die off

Tags: society, science-fiction

If there was a mass human die off, let's say due to a super-flu pandemic, what would be the greatest danger to the survivors in regards to dealing with bodies? Typhoid? Any other secondary diseases? How would survivors best get rid of bodies, esp. if there were few survivors? How long would it take for the bodies to disintegrate naturally?

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange!  This topic has been raised before. Have a look at this : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63421/what-do-you-do-with-all-the-bodies

Comment: As, @MorrisTheCat said, this has been asked and you can find your answer there.  Also, I would like to mention that this site only allows one question per post.  If you have more questions that don't get answered by your first post, ask follow up questions.

Comment: @Morris The Cat Thank you! Sorry I didn't locate that response. It is exactly what I need. :)

Comment: Could you describe the specifics a bit better? E.g. do you have a protagonist with 10 survivors trapped in NYC with everybody dead or are we looking at someone overseeing a large project cleaning up 5% of the population? It's really a different topic depending on quite a lot of things

Comment: Hello user62044, I believe that this question has been wrongly marked as a duplicate. Your question needs to be better defined before that should happen in my view. At present, the way it is written, you have six questions here, you need to narrow it down to just one. You can ask any and all of the other question in seperate question-threads if you wish. Please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] . IMHO the mods were negligent to allow this question to be closed before you were directed to take the tour. Someone should raise this in [meta]. FYI @L.Dutch

Comment: @Agrajag, the OP is leading in determining the scope of the question. They commented with "@Morris The Cat Thank you! Sorry I didn't locate that response. It is exactly what I need. :)". No negligence from my side in acknowledging that.

Comment: @L.Dutch Apologies, I was hasty to comment.